# Isotope Jquery plugin layout issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to set up isotope on this site, it needs to handle the layout and i need to be able to append items to the container.

The issue is that it does not seem to initialize the images properly, here is how i init it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.isotope({
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 400,
            gutterWidth: 10
        },
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: true
        },
        resizesContainer: true,
    });

    load_more();
});
```

The images are completly unaffected by the masonry options, and if i specify "Width" in my CSS i have loading issues.

load_more preforms an ajax call and on success it calls this function with the data returned:

```
function data_loaded(data) {

    var newItems = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data['posts'].length; i++) {
        newItems += '<div class="item" ><img class="gallery_img" src="'+data['posts'][i]['images'][0]['path']+'" /></div>';
    }

    /* append images*/
    var $newItemsObj = $(newItems);
    $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $newItemsObj );
}
```

The site is      http://www.hotchinesebabes.com/
**The site is safe for work, there are no nude images**

It also seems like the site needs a refresh to load properly, i guess the images get catched the second time, so it fails the first time due to triggering isotope prior to image load ?

Comment: Who cares about the domain name? Site is safe for work, if i named it hello kitty adventures it would be okay?

Comment: Yes, yes it is, there are no nude or semi nude images on that website.

Comment: Id like to know what kind of job you have, considering it is not okay to look at fully dressed women.

Comment: If you care about IE browser support, remove the trailing comma: `resizesContainer: true,`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isotope will not work because your images haven't loaded yet, so the width and height of images are 0.  Use https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded or fix the height and width of your images with CSS.