# Div elements overlap on portfolio

Tags: html, css, overlap

I encounter a problem when creating my portfolio... 
It is done using the isotope filter to filter projects by categories.

The problem is that during the first loading, the elements of the portfolio overlap instead of being arranged in a grid of 4 columns.

After selecting a category everything seems resolved, I have scanned the code but can not find where my error came from.
Here is [a link](http://tissier8u.0fees.us/wordpress/portfolio-2/) of the page concerned, temporarily hosted free of charge, in order to have access to the code.

thank you in advance

Julian

Comment: I've tried it, and on the first loading it appears correctly, 4x4x3... and I can't see any overlap

Comment: Hello ,
thank you for your quick reply.
The problem seems to occur only on Google Chrome, can you try on this browser?

Comment: Ok, I see... Maybe it can be related to the images that aren't fully loaded so isotope hasn't time enough to make its own calculations...
Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235772/2990234

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem actually came from there!
After some research and adding the ImagesLoaded function, everything works perfectly.
Good evening to you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Isotope filtering so maybe someone else can chime in there.

But the reason why your boxes are overlapping is because you use absolute positioning on them. The effect of using absolute positioning is that the elements using it are taken out of the document flow, meaning they don't take other elements into account.

On the first row of boxes you've got a top position of 0, 18 on the second row and 36 on the third row.

You might want to look into floats and static/relative positioning or you can start learning about Flexbox if you haven't already (it's starting to get [awesome browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)). Also, in the near future we can use CSS Grids for this very purpose. But that's [not an effective solution](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) as of writing this.

Answer (score 0):

I also think flexbox would be your solution.
You can read/learn more about flexbox here: http://flexboxgrid.com/